# How to output the exact expected topics proportions data in R stm?

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2j2m.png)I am trying to construct a table with topic labels, topic proportions, and top words. I have already used the plot function to generate the top topics figure directly. However, I  can not get the exact proportions of each topic. How can I get the expected topics proportions %? I wonder if there anyone can give me some advice or example so that I can output the data?

thanks for your help.

[Topic summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2j2m.png)

Comment: You might be looking for `tidytext::tidy(YourLDAObject, matrix = "gamma")`, or `YourLDAObject@gamma`.  Both return the gamma per topic. Your question is not quite clear to me though.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Let me say it more clearly. I used STM package in R, trying to output the expected topics proportions data.The package plot function can generate the top topics figure directly, but without exact proportions % of each topic.